# jQuery for each element

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple table data fetch on a page which I want to submit into another table after some process.

My data is like :

```
    <table id="dayfields">
        <tr>
            <td class="f_name">Mr. XYZ</td>
            <td class="p_age">50/M</td>
            <td class="p_days"><input type="text" name="days" id="days" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="f_name">Ms. ABC</td>
            <td class="p_age">36/F</td>
            <td class="p_days"><input type="text" name="days" id="days" /></td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="f_name">Mr. KKK</td>
            <td class="p_age">40/M</td>
            <td class="p_days"><input type="text" name="days" id="days" /></td>            
        </tr>

      <tr><a href="#" id="save">Save</a></tr>

    </table>
```

And jQuery code am trying :

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#save').click(function() {
                var f_name={};
                var p_age={};
                var p_days={};
                var k=0;

                $("#dayfields").each(function () { 
                    f_name[k]=$(this).val();
                    p_age[k]=$(this).val();
                    p_days[k]=$(this).val();
                    k++;
                });
            console.log(f_name);
            }); 
        });
   </script>
```

I found this code on Stackoverflow - but console gives me blank result.

Comment: You have duplicated element ids. It won't work. Use classes when you need to select multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using each loop on `table` change it to `tr`
2. `val()` is not valid function for `td` so change it to [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
3. Find td from tr and add to array by `class` name or index 
   check this:-

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#save').click(function() {
               var f_name={};
               var p_age={};
               var p_days={};
               var k=0;

               $("#dayfields tr:not(:last-child)").each(function () { 
                   f_name[k]=$(this).find('.f_name').text();
                   p_age[k]=$(this).find('.p_age').text();
                   p_days[k]=$(this).find('.p_days').find('input').val();
                   k++;
               });
           console.log(JSON.stringify(f_name));
           }); 
       });
   ```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/21/)

Answer (score 0):

First you should iterate tr's instead of tables.

Second you put the same thing in all arrays $(this).val().

Please check below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#save').click(function() {
                var f_name={};
                var p_age={};
                var p_days={};
                var k=0;

                $("#dayfields tr").each(function () { 

                    f_name[k]=$(this).find(".f_name").html(); 
                    p_age[k]=$(this).find(".p_age").html(); 
                    p_days[k]=$(this).find(".p_days").html(); 
                    k++;
                });
            console.log(f_name);
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: #calinaadi : console gives result as "Object {}"